# Using transforms when zoomed in?

Tags: transforms

How can you use transforms like move when you are zoomed in too much to see the controls anymore? For example you are modeling an object that has the move controller on the bottom of the object but want to model some details on the very top of the object. If you zoom in to that area of the model you can't see the move controller anymore.

Comment: You could have another view open and move the transform in that view but if it is possible to move the control in the original view that would probably be best for efficiency. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the 3D transformation "widget" or armature bones? Edit Mode? Object Mode? Assuming you mean the widget...

You may want to set the *[Pivot Point](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html)*, which will control where the widget is displayed, along with the origin used for scaling and rotation. In EDIT mode (where most detailed modeling is done), if set to anything other than "3D Cursor", it should appear at the selected vertex. In OBJECT or EDIT mode, you could set it to "3D Cursor" and move it around by placing the cursor. (Of course this is of limited use when rotating or scaling)

But, the best solution is to not use the transformation widget at all. Blender was made with the idea of one hand on the keyboard, and one on the mouse. To perform transformations, just use keyboard shortcuts <kbd>G</kbd> to Grab (Translate), <kbd>R</kbd> to Rotate (and <kbd>R</kbd> again for Trackball style rotation), and <kbd>S</kbd> to Scale. You can also use the keyboard to constrain to a single axis with <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, or the middle mouse button. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> when selecting an axis to lock that axis and use the other two.

Comment: using the widget in edit mode

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cursor.

If you click to locate your cursor where you can see it, then you can hit <kbd>.</kbd> to make your controls popup there. To place it back to the object's origin hit <kbd>,</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar trouble. You can nudge (or rather tweak) the object into place once your zoomed in with

**Object > Transform > Move** and then position the object with the mouse.

[image: move Tweak]